# apache2 / nodejs / express on a digital ocean server - how to listen to public port (80) without address in use error

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, apache, express

I'm new to nodejs in a server environment, and trying to figure out how to make it work in conjunction with all of the other things I have running on my digital ocean server.

I was successfully able to set up a sandbox environment on a subdomain on digital ocean in which I have an express server listening for requests from port 3000. Then, from a web browser on port 3000, I could make an ajax GET request to the node server, and retrieve a response.

However, now I am trying to implement that sandbox envionrment into a new subdomain, where I am running the craft PHP CMS. This runs off the default port of 80. So I want my node server to be able to listen to requests from port 80. But where before I could say:

```
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('listening')
})
```

If I were to try to run craft off of Port 3000, it would throw an error for the URL routing: `Cannot GET [url_segments]`

because it is designed to look for requests from port 80, the default web port. And if I change the express server to listen to port 80, it gives an error saying the address is in use.

```
> node app.js:
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::80
```

How do I get `app.js` to just listen to the default public html port on my digital ocean server without this EADDRINUSE error? I want people to visit my subdomain:

`http://subdomain.domain.com/episodes/episode-2`

and have it be able to make calls via AJAX to my express server:

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var startDate = urlParams.get('start');
var endDate = urlParams.get('end');
var urlWithParams = "/list?start=" + startDate + "&end=" + endDate;

$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: urlWithParams,
}).done(function (data) {
    //do stuff
})
```

where the list function on my express server is something like:

```
let app = express()

app.get('/list', (request, response) => {
  //DO STUFF
}
```

I am on a digital ocean server using Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache2

Comment: are you using nginx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a proxy.

**nginx example:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.domain.com

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }   
}
```

**Apache:**

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

[More info here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension)

Comment: where do I declare this?

Comment: In your `nginx.conf`  placed in the directory /usr/local/nginx/conf, /etc/nginx, or /usr/local/etc/nginx.

Comment: Oh, I'm using apache - should've mentioned. Seems like nginx is way easier though - most of the examples I see deal with this.

Comment: Ah yes nginx is easier! Good luck I updated my answer.  Check this tutorial too http://blog.podrezo.com/making-node-js-work-with-apache/

Comment: Probably want to set that subdomain and path in that <VirtualHost> directive too.

Comment: Just a bit of clarification for my specific issue in case it helps anyone - I wanted my regular apache server to serve up everything except for a few node.js specific urls, so my virtual host directive looked like: `ProxyRequests on
 ProxyPass /recordings/ http://localhost:3001/recordings/
 ProxyPass /list http://localhost:3001/list` - that allowed any requests for the URL /recordings/ or /list/ to pass through to the node server to process vs the apache server. The `ProxyPassReverse` was not needed in my case.